# How to validate the date input controls in Jasper Server/Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to put validations on these dates like:

1) END_DATE should not be less than START_DATE
2) START_DATE should not be greater than END_DATE

Answer (score 0):

You could use variables for this case. I created a similar name and reproduced your requirements.

```
<variable name="START_DATE_corr" class="java.util.Date">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{START_DATE}.getTime() > $F{END_DATE}.getTime()) ? $F{END_DATE} : $F{START_DATE}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>

<variable name="END_DATE_corr" class="java.util.Date">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{END_DATE}.getTime() < $F{START_DATE} ? $F{START_DATE} : $F{END_DATE}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Afterwards you can use the variables

```
$V{START_DATE_corr}
$V{END_DATE_corr}
```

in your report.

Comment: But i need in input controls level validations.

Comment: I'm afraid input control level validation is only used to check if the correct format of *only one parameter at a time* is in a correct data format to prevent malicious use of parameters.